# custom package(__init__.ipynb)

Tags: python, init

I understand that there should be an empty `__init__.py` (`.ipynb`) file when loading into a custom package.
I'm implementing a paper, and there's a function defined as def inside the `__init__`
I have to bring this up, but I can't.

Is there a separate way to load the functions in the `__init__` file?

Comment: I don't know what you mean by *"I have to bring this [function] up"*, do you mean import it? define it? import it from somewhere else in your package hierarchy? Can you show your package outline in terms of file(s), functions, classes and directories? (Also in Python we wouldn't say *"a function defined as `def`"*, I'd just say function, all functions are defined by `def`, except for `lambda`.)

Comment: tflib folder -> __init__.py -> def print_model_settings(locals_):                                                           

'import tflib as lib'                                                                                                          

'lib.print_model_settings(locals().copy()'                                                                     

-> error : module 'tflib' has no attribute 'print_model_settings'

Comment: What does `dir(lib)` show? Was anything successfully imported from `tflib`? Try to define some other constant or function in tflib to see if it imports ok. Also, what runtime directory are you in? (Don't run from inside tflib directories.)